# Зависимость стиля виджетов от пользователя.

Tags: qt, c++

Сижу на линуксе. Проблема в следующем: при запуске программы от рута и пользователя виджеты отображаются по-разному, даже иконки стандартные и те ведут себя также. Попробовал `QApplication::setStyle(styleName)`, но как-то не помогает. Можно как-нибудь жестко задать стиль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно просто настроить стили для рута. И все будет хорошо. Рут - это другой пользователь. Совсем другой.

*Обновление*

Все зависит от того, какой набор контролов используете (gtk или qt). В случае gtk нужно найти в домашнем каталоге каталог, где лежит файл `gtk-3.0/settings.ini` (для второго так сходу не знаю) и скопировать его в аналогичное место для рута. (но скорее всего не один файл придется копировать, а несколько.)

У меня  на федоре эта проблема решилась очень просто - там есть утилита [fedy](http://satya164.github.io/fedy/), которая кроме всего прочего умеет в один клик решать эту проблему.

Comment: А не подскажите как?) Что-то найти по этому поводу не могу ничего.